# Linking project compiled with C++, referencing C project which references C++ project

Tags: c++, c, extern

I have 3 projects in a solution: CppProject1 (C++), CProject (C) and CppProject2(C++)

CProject depends on CppProject1

CppProject2 depends on CProject.

```
CppProject2 -> CProject -> CppProject1
```

What I am trying to achieve is call C++ method from CProject.

CppProject1 contains following files:

```
///c_wrapper.h

#ifndef _C_WRAPPER_H__
#define _C_WRAPPER_H__
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif
EXTERNC void findMarkers(int width, int height, unsigned char* dataPtr);
#endif

///c_wrapper.cpp

#include "c_wrapper.h"

void findMarkers(int width, int height, unsigned char* dataPtr) {
    //nothing
}
```

if I compile and link CProject (`CProject -> CppProject1`) everything is okay .

If I try to compile and link CppProject2 (`CppProject2 -> CProject -> CppProject1`) I get 
`LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _findMarkers`

Comment: Guess you have to add EXTERNC in the .cpp file as well. C++ allows overloading on linkage.

Comment: A function name in C is taken as it is in the linker. In C++ every function wich is not extern "C" has it's name mangled (whether it's for importing or exporting the symbol).

Comment: @BoPersson I don't believe it's needed. And although different overloads can have different language linkages, those two declarations are the same overload (identical signatures). See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage#Notes.

Comment: What does the CppProject2 code look like?

Comment: @Alan - I was thinking of functions like [atexit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) which is declared twice in the standard library, once with "C" linkage and once with "C++" linkage. The same thing might happen here.

Comment: @Bo I think those are overloaded on the supplied function parameter - which themselves have different language linkage.

Comment: Calling a _method_ from C is problematic. But calling a _function_ should be possible.